# C: create random numbers from a range that are all different

Tags: c, random

For example, I have these 3 variables:

```
N = 5;
int r1 = rand() % N;
int r2 = rand() % N;
int r3 = rand() % N;
```

How can I get 3 different numbers in that range that are not the same?
I tried with this code:

```
do{
  int r1 = rand() % N;
  int r2 = rand() % N;
  int r3 = rand() % N;
}while((r1 == r2) && (r1==r3) && (r2==r3));
```

but it doesn't work. Sometimes one or two numbers are the same (ex: 1, 1, 4).
But I need them all to be different. How can I do this?

Comment: `}while (r1 == r2 || r1==r3 || r2==r3);`

Comment: Better yet, if you only have 5 different values, put them in an array, pick an array index at random, replace that one with the last element value, reduce the number of elements for `rand() % elements`. Look up Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: ... and beware: `rand() % 5` is not unbiased. (the lowest few values have higher expectation to occur)

Comment: If you don't want the numbers to be the same, you don't want random numbers.  @WeatherVane has the best solution for you this far as even if you change your code's `&&` to `||`, you can end up spinning a whole bunch of extra numbers, and depending on how random is created, perhaps (small perhaps) never even exit the loop.  This chance gets higher as you test against more numbers...

Comment: @wildplasser The bias in `rand() % 5` will be undetectable under most circumstances -- it's about 0.003%, I believe.  (If it was `rand() % 30000`, on the other hand, that might be a different story.)

Comment: I realise it is futile. But it could save you some money when playing (or exploiting ;-) one-armed bandits. [best way to save money BTW is not to play them]

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, if the numbers can't be the same, then it's simply random sampling without replacement.  The random draws aren't *independent*, but they're still random.  The full process can be described equivalently as a single 3-tuple drawn from a joint distribution where tuples with duplicate values have probability 0 and all other possibilities are uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will pick 3 different numbers in the range 0..4. It works by creating an array of available numbers, as one each is picked it is removed from the list. This removes the inefficiency of repeatedly attempting to fulfil the condition that all are different - which might **NEVER** happen with a true RNG!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define RANGE   5                   // how many different numbers
#define PICK    3                   // how many to pick

int main(void) {
    int pool[RANGE];
    int size, n, i;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (size=0; size<RANGE; size++) {
        pool[size] = size;          // create number pool
    }

    // pick different numbers
    for(i=0; i<PICK; i++) {
        n = rand() % size;          // random array index
        printf("%d ", pool[n]);     // select number from pool
        pool[n] = pool[--size];     // remove from pool
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```